# EveryCircuit-Simulator Specific shortcomings

Tags: simulation, back-emf

Just sent this to EveryCircuit

```
Hi, 

 I love the app, and recently subscribed to it. But I'd like to find more gadgets in it:
// feature requests 

  1)  Common core inductors. Transformers are the closest I found but only have two inductors. So it'd be cool (and necessary for some projects) to be able to simulate:
   * Core material and type.
   * Inductor quantity. 
    ** per inductor: Mass, turns & winding type (e.g. bifilar A with B but not C etc.). I guess this could be simplified with the "Coupling factor" setting between inductors, but how would one know a realistic value?
  2) Spark Gap for high voltage experiments. with different:
   * Distance/dielectric => breakdown voltage  
   * Quench => magnetic, air flow. 
  3) Mosfet gating time. a key characteristic of real mosfets. 



// Bugs ?
Some issues I bumped into:
* I'm also getting "Cant find solution" on my VIC (Meyer's voltage intensifier circuit) simulation, randomly.
* Back emf when abruptly opening the circuit of a coil has a voltage that depends on simulation speed, the slower the higher Voltage gets. So how can I get a realistic voltage?
* Sometimes the voltage from a BEMF can be captured in a capacitor, Sometimes it can't. All these issues can be found in my circuit "BEMF and VIC voltage intensifier circuit" public circuit..
* Why is the "coupling factor" in a transformer able to be set greater than 1?
```

Was wondering if the community has some work arounds for the feature requests and/or any idea on why the "Bugs" happen.

Answer (score 1):

EveryCircuit is a poorly/non supported app at the moment, and I don’t even think this question is on topic here. The only “workaround” is not to use it.

I have used it for a few days and frankly a most basic breadboard, parts and tools beat it handily. That’s not the case even for CircuitLab, and that one is not great either compared to even open source spice.

As to why the “bugs” happen? That’s not specific to that particular app. Usually the developer(s) have not enough resources to do the job right. Call it economic reality or whatnot.

Comment: Thanks, will check out the mentioned apps. This one looked pro LOL